# Why does MPI_Send is blocking when i try to send 2D int array?

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I'm trying to perform a fractal picture parallel calcul with mpi.
I've divide my program in 4 part :

1. Balance the number of row treat by each rank
2. Perform the calcul on each row attribute to the rank
3. Sending the number of row and the rows to the rank 0
4. Treat the data in rank 0 (for the test just print the int)

The step 1 and 2 are working but when i'm trying to send the rows to rank 0 the program is stoping and block. I know that the MPI_Send could Block bu there is no reason for that here.

Here is the 2 first step:

Step 1 :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Include the MPI library for function calls */
#include <mpi.h>

/* Define tags for each MPI_Send()/MPI_Recv() pair so distinct messages can be
 * sent */
#define OTHER_N_ROWS_TAG 0
#define OTHER_PIXELS_TAG 1

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  const int nRows = 513;
  const int nCols = 513;
  const int middleRow = 0.5 * (nRows - 1);
  const int middleCol = 0.5 * (nCols - 1);
  const double step = 0.00625;
  const int depth = 100;
  int pixels[nRows][nCols];
  int row;
  int col;
  double xCoord;
  double yCoord;
  int i;
  double x;
  double y;
  double tmp;
  int myRank;
  int nRanks;
  int evenSplit;
  int nRanksWith1Extra;
  int myRow0;
  int myNRows;
  int rank;
  int otherNRows;
  int otherPixels[nRows][nCols];

  /* Each rank sets up MPI */
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  /* Each rank determines its ID and the total number of ranks */
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myRank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nRanks);
  printf("My rank is %d \n",myRank);
  evenSplit = nRows / nRanks;
  nRanksWith1Extra = nRows % nRanks;

/*Each rank determine the number of rows that he will have to perform (well balanced)*/
  if (myRank < nRanksWith1Extra) {

    myNRows = evenSplit + 1;
    myRow0 = myRank * (evenSplit + 1);
  }
  else {
    myNRows = evenSplit;
    myRow0 = (nRanksWith1Extra * (evenSplit + 1)) +
      ((myRank - nRanksWith1Extra) * evenSplit);
  }
/*__________________________________________________________________________________*/
```

Step 2 :

```
/*_____________________PERFORM CALCUL ON EACH PIXEL________________________________ */
  for (row = myRow0; row < myRow0 + myNRows; row++) {

    /* Each rank loops over the columns in the given row */
    for (col = 0; col < nCols; col++) {

      /* Each rank sets the (x,y) coordinate for the pixel in the given row and 
       * column */
      xCoord = (col - middleCol) * step;
      yCoord = (row - middleRow) * step;

      /* Each rank calculates the number of iterations for the pixel in the
       * given row and column */
      i = 0;
      x = 0;
      y = 0;
      while ((x*x + y*y < 4) && (i < depth)) {
        tmp = x*x - y*y + xCoord;
        y = 2*x*y + yCoord;
        x = tmp;
        i++;
      }

      /* Each rank stores the number of iterations for the pixel in the given
       * row and column. The initial row is subtracted from the current row
       * so the array starts at 0 */
      pixels[row - myRow0][col] = i;
    }
      //printf("one row performed by %d \n",myRank);

  }
      printf("work done by %d \n",myRank);
/*_________________________________________________________________________________*/
```

Step 3:

```
/*__________________________SEND DATA TO RANK 0____________________________________*/

  /* Each rank (including Rank 0) sends its number of rows to Rank 0 so Rank 0
   * can tell how many pixels to receive */
  MPI_Send(&myNRows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, OTHER_N_ROWS_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  printf("test \n");
  /* Each rank (including Rank 0) sends its pixels array to Rank 0 so Rank 0
   * can print it */
  MPI_Send(&pixels, sizeof(int)*myNRows * nCols, MPI_BYTE, 0, OTHER_PIXELS_TAG,
      MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  printf("enter ranking 0 \n");
/*_________________________________________________________________________________*/
```

Step 4:

```
/*________________________TREAT EACH ROW IN RANK 0_________________________________*/
  /* Only Rank 0 prints so the output is in order */
  if (myRank == 0) {

    /* Rank 0 loops over each rank so it can receive that rank's messages */
    for (rank = 0; rank < nRanks; rank++){

      /* Rank 0 receives the number of rows from the given rank so it knows how
       * many pixels to receive in the next message */
      MPI_Recv(&otherNRows, 1, MPI_INT, rank, OTHER_N_ROWS_TAG,
      MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

      /* Rank 0 receives the pixels array from each of the other ranks
       * (including itself) so it can print the number of iterations for each
       * pixel */
      MPI_Recv(&otherPixels, otherNRows * nCols, MPI_INT, rank,
          OTHER_PIXELS_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

      /* Rank 0 loops over the rows for the given rank */
      for (row = 0; row < otherNRows; row++) {

        /* Rank 0 loops over the columns within the given row */
        for (col = 0; col < nCols; col++) {

          /* Rank 0 prints the value of the pixel at the given row and column
           * followed by a comma */
          printf("%d,", otherPixels[row][col]);
        }

        /* In between rows, Rank 0 prints a newline character */
        printf("\n");
      }
    }
  }

  /* All processes clean up the MPI environment */
  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

I would like to understand why does it blocking , could you explain me ? 
I'm a new user of MPI and i would like to learn it not just to have a program that is working.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MPI_Send` is *by definition* of the standard a **blocking** operation.

Note that blocking means:

> it does not return until the message data and envelope have been safely stored away so that the sender is free to modify the send buffer. The message might be copied directly into the matching receive buffer, or it might be copied into a temporary system buffer.

Trying to have a rank send messages to itself with `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` is a deadlock.

The idiomatic pattern for your situation is to use the appropriate collective communication operations `MPI_Gather` and `MPI_Gatherv`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use blocking send/recv constructs when sending to the rank 0 itself, it might cause a deadlock.

From the [MPI 3.0 standard, Section 3.2.4](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node50.htm#Node50):

> Source = destination is allowed, that is, a process can send a message to itself.  (However, it is unsafe to do so with the blocking send and receive operations described above,
>   since this may lead to deadlock.  See Section 3.5.)

Possible solutions:

- Use non-blocking send/recv constructs when sending/receiving to/from rank 0 itself. For more information, take a look at the [MPI_Isend](http://mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Isend.html), [MPI_Irecv](http://mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Irecv.html) and [MPI_Wait](http://mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Wait.html) routines.
- Eliminate communication with rank 0 itself. Since you are in rank 0, you already have a way to know how many pixels you have to compute.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in a previous answer, `MPI_Send()` **might** block.

From a theoretical `MPI` point of view, your application is incorrect because of a potential deadlock (rank `0` `MPI_Send()` to itself when no receive is posted).

From a very pragmatic point of view, `MPI_Send()` generally returns immediately when a *small* message is sent (such as `myNRows`), but blocks until a matching receive is posted when a *large* message is sent (such as `pixels`). Please keep in mind

- *small* and *large* depend at least on both the MPI library and the interconnect being used
- it is incorrect from a `MPI` point of view to assume that `MPI_Send()` will return immediately for `small` messages

If you really want to make sure your application is deadlock free, you can simply replace `MPI_Send()` with `MPI_Ssend()`.

Back to your question, there are several options here

- revamp your app so rank `0` does not communicate with itself (all the info is available, so no communication is needed
- post a `MPI_Irecv()` before `MPI_Send()`, and replace `MPI_Recv(source=0)` with `MPI_Wait()`
- revamp you app so rank `0` does not `MPI_Send()` nor `MPI_Recv(source=0)`, but `MPI_Sendrecv` instead. This is my recommended option since you only have to make a small change to the communication pattern (the computation pattern is kept untouched) which is more elegant imho.